# How can I copy a link URL in either lynx or links to copy to vim?

Tags: linux, lynx

I am having the most difficult time trying to figure out how to copy a link URL in either of these two browsers and then paste it into vim.  Does anyone know how to go about doing this?  I am using Slackware 13.1.  Any alternatives to copy/paste are also acceptable.

Comment: This helped https://superuser.com/a/82991/332604

Answer (score 5):

I did a quick search, and I found this:

https://superuser.com/questions/82969/how-do-i-copy-a-link-in-lynx

Looks like you hover over the link and "shift+e" (or "shift+g" for current page) and copy it with "ctrl+shift+c".

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+C doesn't seem to work (Wayland) and isn't mentioned anywhere on the referenced page. Pressing the A key saves the URL to the `lynx` bookmarks file. [`tmux` can be used for copying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58765/172800) for instance (copy to the system clipboard with e.g. [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard).

Answer (score 4):

you can use "screen" command. It has it's own copy-paste mechanism.

Comment: The `screen` command is the way to go.  Start your browser (fan of elinks myself), get the URL to show up, click `Ctrl a` `Ctrl [` and use arrow keys to get the cursor at the start of URL, click `Enter` arrow keys to end, click `Enter`.  Switch to vim using `Ctrl a` and number of screen and hit `i` and `Ctrl a` `Ctrl ]`.  That should do it.  Much easier than it reads.

Answer (score 1):

If you would ssh into the server, rather than sitting at the console, then you could just use normal mouse selection to copy and paste. The cut and paste is handled by a GUI like X or Windows 7 or MacOS GUI. It is part of the terminal app.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save the URL of the current page or the current link (at least on my version 2.8.8).

(Unfortunately, I'm currently getting an error "Copy to clipboard failed", but maybe someone else is more lucky.)